# angular ui-router test state

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router, state

I'm writing up a series of unit tests for a login module.  Right now, all the failures are being applied as expected.  However, I'm having an issue testing a valid login because the test is returning an error `Could not resolve 'models' from state ''` for the valid login test.

Given an authentication service that takes in a return message from the server and transitions

```
angular.module('qServices').service('qsAuthentication', function($resource, qsSession, 
               REST_ROOT, $state){

    var Session = $resource(REST_ROOT + 'session');

    this.login = function(credentials, errorHandler){

        //does a POST
        Session.save({}, credentials, function(response){
            if (response.success === true){
                qsSession.refresh();
                $state.go('models'); //TODO: "default" state
            }
```

and the state is defined in

```
angular.module('qRouting', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('models', {
        parent: 'base',
        templateUrl: 'modules/models/models-view.html',
        controller: 'qcModels',
        url: '/models'
    })
```

So, basically what happens here is if `response.success` is true, the state transitions to the `/models` URL and loads the approprate template.  Unfortunately, the test is returning an error `Could not resolve 'models' from state ''` for the test

```
describe("Login Test: ", function()
{
    var $httpBackend,
        rootScope,
        scope,
        qsAuthentication,
        loginError,
        REST_ROOT,
        state,
        templateCache;

    beforeEach(module("qLogin"));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector)
    {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
        REST_ROOT = $injector.get("REST_ROOT");
        state = $injector.get("$state");
        qsAuthentication = $injector.get("qsAuthentication");
        rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
        scope = rootScope.$new();
        templateCache = $injector.get("$templateCache");

        scope.credentials = {
            username : "dummytest",
            password : "dummypass"
        };

        loginError = function(errorMessage)
        {
            scope.loginErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        };

        templateCache.put('modules/models/models-view.html');
    }));

    it("Should send a valid login request", function ()
    {
        $httpBackend.expectPOST(REST_ROOT + "session", scope.credentials)
            .respond(200, {success : true});
        qsAuthentication.login(scope.credentials, loginError);
        rootScope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(state.current.name).toBe("models");
    });
};
```

The error happens at

```
$state.go("models");
```

line in the service.  How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, that we are facing "missing module dependency" here.

The point is, that module **`qLogin`** which will be tested :

```
// this module will be tested
beforeEach(module("qLogin"));
...
```

Is working with state **`'models'`** - defined in other module **`'qRouting'`**:

```
angular.module('qRouting', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider){

        $stateProvider.state('models', {
        ...
```

While we cannot see the module **`'qLogin'`** declaration (setter), I would expect, that it is missing the dependency to module *`'qRouting'`*:

```
// module 'qRouting' is not having access to qLogin
angular.module('qRouting', ['ui.router'])
```

So, solution here should be extending that module declaration

```
// now we have state 'models' in the test domain
angular.module('qRouting', ['ui.router', 'qLogin'])
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Looks like we have some refactoring to do in regards to route states and feature modules.

Comment: Exactly. Honestly, I have to say, that in our application - THIS state- was the reason to reduce the amount of modules. In fact, for app we have just one. Some others for really isolated components...